# error trying to delete value using laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

im trying to delete a value in my laravel project but im having error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI:
>   chatbot/deleteEntityValue/{companyID}/{entityType}/{entityValue}].
>   (View:
>   C:\xamppNew\htdocs\althr\resources\views\AltHr\Chatbot\prebuiltQA.blade.php)

what i did was created a href link

```
<a href="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\PreBuiltController@deleteEntityValue', $companyID, $entityType, $entityValue)}}" class="btn alt-btn-black btn-sm alt-btn pull-right fixed-btn-del">Delete</a>
```

and in my routes define it as

```
Route::get('deleteEntityValue/{companyID}/{entityType}/{entityValue}','Chatbot\PreBuiltController@deleteEntityValue');
```

and in my controller

```html
public function deleteEntityValue($companyID, $entityType, $entityValue)
  {
    $companyID = $this->decode($companyID);
    
    return view('AltHr.Chatbot.prebuiltQA', compact('entityType','entityValue','companyID'));
  }
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Read the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing parameters in a wrong way

```
<a href="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\PreBuiltController@deleteEntityValue', [$companyID, $entityType, $entityValue])}}" class="btn alt-btn-black btn-sm alt-btn pull-right fixed-btn-del">Delete</a>
```

`action()` method requires parameters as array

You can also url() like this

```
<a href="{{url('/deleteEntityValue/')}}{{$companyID}}/{{$entityType}}/{{$entityValue}}"class="btn alt-btn-black btn-sm alt-btn pull-right fixed-btn-del">Delete</a>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

use `URL::to()`

```
<a href="{{URL::to('/deleteEntityValue/'.$companyID.'/'.$entityType.'/'.$entityValue)}}" class="btn alt-btn-black btn-sm alt-btn pull-right fixed-btn-del">Delete</a>
```

or try this with `plain` html-

```
<a href="/deleteEntityValue/{{$companyID}}/{{$entityType}}/{{$entityValue}}" class="btn alt-btn-black btn-sm alt-btn pull-right fixed-btn-del">Delete</a>
```